# How to join strings in MySQL as PHP join function?

Tags: php, mysql, perl, join

I have this data structure in MySQL:

```
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| name      | barcode   | factory_code |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
| product 1 | 123456789 |              |
| product 2 | 987654321 |              |
| product 3 |           | AAAAAAAAAAAA |
| product 4 |           | BBBBBBBBBBBB |
| product 5 | 111111111 | CCCCCCCCCCCC |
+-----------+-----------+--------------+
```

And now I need to generate this result and show in HTML:

```
+-----------+-------------------------+
| name      | code                    |
+-----------+-------------------------+
| product 1 | 123456789               |
| product 2 | 987654321               |
| product 3 | AAAAAAAAAAAA            |
| product 4 | BBBBBBBBBBBB            |
| product 5 | 111111111, CCCCCCCCCCCC |
+-----------+-------------------------+
```

The fields are not `NULL`, just empty.

I think I generate this with a MySQL query directly, to code less and maybe it will be work faster a little bit. I can do it with PHP's / Perl's `join` function.

It is possible to do directly in MySQL?

Comment: So `mysql string concat` shows your nothing?

Comment: The missing values are null / empty?

Comment: They are empty. Not NULL.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`concat_ws()` in MySQL](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/string-functions.html#function_concat). Since you don't have `NULL` but empty strings, you will need to implement a bit of logic to filter out those empty fields.

```
SELECT 
    name, 
    concat_ws(
        ', ', 
        IF(barcode > "", barcode, NULL),
        IF(factory_code > "", factory_code, NULL)
    ) as 'code' 
FROM Table1;
```

As [Borodin points out in his comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38804823/how-to-join-strings-in-mysql-as-php-join-function/38804828?noredirect=1#comment64979451_38804828), if `barcode`contains spaces or control characters then it will not be equal to the empty string, so `barcode = ""` will fail and the result will be a spurious comma. But MySQL space-extends the two parameters of a comparison, so anything that contains a non-space character will be "greater than" anything that doesn't. `IF (barcode > "", barcode, NULL)` turns to `NULL` anything that is just control characters (HT, LF, CR etc.) or spaces.

Try it [here](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/ae727/1/0).

However, it's not going to give you a lot more speed to have the DB do it. For this rather small amount of data, it is negligible and I think it's not even worth thinking about.

In Perl, you would also have to add checks for empty strings.

```
while (my $res = $sth->fetchrow_arrayref) {
    my $name = shift @$res;
    my $code = join ', ', grep { $_ } @$res;
    # and then do stuff
}
```

The `grep { $_ } @$res` filters out all values that are not considered to be a *true value*. That is, empty strings as well as `NULL` values, which are represented by `undef`.

From a maintenance perspective (if that matters), going with doing it in the application rather than the SQL is preferable<sup>1</sup>. If it's throwaway code, I would personally go with the one that takes me the least amount of thinking.

<sup>1) That is, if we are talking about plain SQL mixed inside of a small application. On a larger scale, and if there is an actual model layer, I would move the aggregation into that model.</sup>

Comment: `concat_ws` shows this ', BBBBBBBBBBBB' ... but the fields are not `NULL` just empty.

Comment: "From a maintenance perspective (if that matters), going with doing it in the application rather than the SQL is preferable." Couldn't agree less.

Comment: @Walf why? Please explain.

Comment: @Walf: That comment has left most of us unable to fathom what you're talking about. Do you have a real point? Most of us would prefer to reduce the source of a bug as quickly as possible. You seem to be alone in your hope that the functionality is spread over at least two domains.

Comment: I suggest `IF (barcode > "", barcode, NULL)` so that all-blank  fields are also ignored.

Comment: @Borodin I don't see the difference. Can you explain how this behaves different from `= ""` please?

Comment: @simbabque: If `barcode` contains spaces or control characters then it will not be equal to the empty string, so `barcode = ""` will fail and the result will be a spurious comma. But MySQL space-extends the two parameters of a comparison, so anything that contains a non-space character will be "greater than" anything that doesn't. `IF (barcode > "", barcode, NULL)` turns to NULL anything that is just control characters (HT, LF, CR etc.) or spaces.

Comment: @Borodin thank you. that makes sense. I added it to the answer.

Comment: @simbabque, @borodin If you're always modifying the data as it comes out of the database in the same manner, i.e. defining the model, it's better to have it in that format before it ever gets to the app, then it is the same regardless of the method of retrieving the data. Ideally it should be in a `VIEW`.

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like that:

```
SET @a := 'abc';
SET @b :='def';

SELECT CONCAT(@a, IF(LENGTH(@a) >0 AND LENGTH(@b) >0,',',''), @b)
```

<sub>Replace `@a` by `barcode` and `@b` by `factory_code`</sub>

**In your case:**

```
SELECT
    name,
    CONCAT(
            barcode,
            IF(LENGTH(barcode) > 0  AND LENGTH(factory_code) > 0, ',', ''),
            factory_code
    ) AS 'code'
FROM t;
```

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/72742/1)</kbd>  <sub>When @a and @b are non-empty</sub>

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/72743)</kbd>  <sub>When @a empty and @b non-empty</sub>

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/72745)</kbd>  <sub>When @a non-empty and @b empty</sub>

<kbd>[**WORKING DEMO**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/9eecb7d/72744/2)</kbd>  <sub>When @a and @b are empty</sub>

Comment: **To whom it may concern:** Please state the reason behind downvoting so that I can refine my knowledge. Downvoting silently doesn't add anything `(+) ve`

Answer (score 0):

I find a simple solution based on [1000111](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1714187/1000111)'s answer.

```
SELECT CONCAT_WS(', ',
          IF( LENGTH(barcode) > 0, barcode, NULL),
          IF( LENGTH(factory_code) > 0, factory_code, NULL) AS code
       FROM tablename;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT name, TRIM(',' FROM TRIM(CONCAT_WS(', ', barcode, factory_code))) as code ...
```